# LINQ - Determine if ListA contains every element from ListB

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I need to compare two lists with LINQ *including* duplicates.
There seems to be a tonne of similar questions, however, I have been searching, and have only found methods that disregard duplicates - only checking if List A contains an item from List B, using Except or Intersect. I had some success using OrderBy and SequenceEquals, but it will only work if the lists are the same size.

```
List<Animal> ListA;
List<Animal> ListB;

// This works..
ListA = { Dog, Dog, Dog, Cat, Mouse }
ListB = { Dog, Dog, Dog, Cat, Mouse }

// However, this does not..
ListA = { Dog, Dog, Dog, Cat, Mouse, Mouse }
ListB = { Dog, Dog, Dog, Cat, Mouse }   

var result = ListA.OrderBy(animal => animal)
                  .SequenceEqual(ListB.OrderBy(animal => animal));
```

I need it to work regardless of the size of List A.

I hope I've managed to explain the situation.
In the actual implementation I'm checking ListA against a list of lists similar to ListB, and creating a new list of 'possible combinations'.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is order important? If order is not important do normal distinct on list of `{element, count}` instead of just list of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to count the occurrences.

```
static bool IsSubsetWithDuplicates<T>(IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset)
{
    var supersetLookup = superset.ToLookup(a => a);
    foreach (var subsetGroup in subset.ToLookup(a => a))
    {
        if(subsetGroup.Count() > supersetLookup[subsetGroup.Key].Count())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Calling code:

```
var result1 = IsSubsetWithDuplicates(ListA, ListB);
var result2 = IsSubsetWithDuplicates(ListA1, ListB1);
var result3 = IsSubsetWithDuplicates(ListB1, ListA1);
```

Comment: I was unaware of ToLookup. This makes perfect sense and does exactly what I need. I was able to incorporate it and it's working great. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extension method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
 List<T> list = target.ToList();
 foreach (T item in source)
 {
  if (list.Contains(item))
  {
   list.Remove(item);
   yield return item;
  }
 }
}
```

provided [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45360806-442c-47eb-b0c2-7aa57cb720cb/how-to-intersect-two-list-without-losing-the-duplicated-values)